# Give multiple values to a var simultaneously

Tags: polynomials

Lets suppose I've got the following equation:
$$
\frac{x}{x-1} = \pm \sqrt{3}
$$
A way to solve could be to separate it into multiple cases and then solve each expression individually.

But if I set $a = \pm 1$ the expression could be turned into something like:
$$
x = (x-1)a\sqrt{3}
$$
$$
x(1-a\sqrt{3}) = -a\sqrt{3}
$$
$$
x = - \frac{a\sqrt{3}}{1-a\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{1+a\sqrt{3}}{1+a\sqrt{3}}
$$
$$
x = - \frac{a\sqrt{3} + 3}{-2} = \frac{\pm\sqrt{3} + 3}{2}
$$
Which is way simpler.
In that case a has simultaneously $2$ values: $+1$ and $-1$. I was wondering if it's possible to set multiple arbitray values to a var simultaneously, for example
$$
b = (3 \vee -4)
$$

Comment: Multiple values can't be held *simultaneously*. When you evaluate an expression you just choose which value you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with solving the equation as is:
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{x-1}&=\pm\sqrt3\\
1+\frac1{x-1}&=\pm\sqrt3\\
\frac1{x-1}&=-1\pm\sqrt3\\
x-1&=\frac1{-1\pm\sqrt3}\\
x&=1+\frac1{-1\pm\sqrt3}
\end{align}
which gives you the two desired solutions.

Comment: Actually that's not the question. The question was if multiple values can be held simultaneously to a variable.